# How do you use jQuery to show html when a HTML select option is clicked?

Tags: jquery, select, click

I have some html that I want shown when a certain `<option>` on a `<select>` was clicked. I have the code below for the HTML below that. Is that how it would be done? It doesn't seem to be working even though there are no errors.

jQuery:

```
$('#addSubject').click(function(){
     $('#pgHide').show();
     $('span.centerMessage').hide();
     $('#addSubjectPopup').show();
});
```

HTML:

```
<select>
     <option id="addSubject">Add Subject</option>
</select>
<div id="pgHide" style="display: none; ">
     <span class="centerMessage">
          <img src="../images/loading.gif" />
     Creating...</span>
     <div class="centerMessage" id="addSubjectPopup" style="display: none;">
          <span class="closePopup">close</span>
          <div id="insideCenterMessage">
          <label>Add Subject</label>
          <input type="text" name="subject" id="addSubjectField">
          <input type="submit" value="Add Subject" id="addSubjectBttn">
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`<option>` elements don't fire click events, only the `<select>`s do. Instead, you can check the selected value of the `<select>` after it's been changed:

```
$('select').change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == 'Add Subject') {
        // Rest of your code
    }
}).change(); // Trigger change immediately to work on DOM-ready
```

---

Or if you prefer to continue to specify the target `<option>` through the HTML, then:

```
$('select').change(function () {
    if ($(this).find('#addSubject:selected').length) {
        // Rest of your code
    }
}).change(); // Trigger change immediately to work on DOM-ready
```

Comment: Keep in mind, however, that "change" only works when the option has been changed. You may need to manually trigger the event if it's selected by default. $(#addSubject').(...stuff before...).trigger('change'); You'll also need to use the change event on the select, not the option.

Comment: shouldn't you capture the change event on the `select` element? Moreover, `.val()` gives the `value` attribute of the selected option under the `select`, which is not there in the OP's markup

Comment: @xixonia, as with clicks as well. I've made the change, cheers.

Comment: this definitely makes sense, thanks. For some reason its not working though. I must have a bug somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to change your markup like this

```
<select id="addSubject">
     <option value="1">Add Subject</option>
</select>
<div id="pgHide" style="display: none; ">
     <span class="centerMessage">
          <img src="../images/loading.gif" />
     Creating...</span>
     <div class="centerMessage" id="addSubjectPopup" style="display: none;">
          <span class="closePopup">close</span>
          <div id="insideCenterMessage">
          <label>Add Subject</label>
          <input type="text" name="subject" id="addSubjectField">
          <input type="submit" value="Add Subject" id="addSubjectBttn">
     </div>
</div>
```

then, use

```
$('#addSubject').change(function (e) {
    if ($(this).val() == 1) {
        // ...
    }
});
```